# PHP Regular Expression ( replace text )

Tags: php, expression

HI Guys why doesnt this reg.exp work ?
The 'TEST' should be replaced with XXX ?

```
<?php
$Rules = array ('@<script[^>]*?>.*?</script>@si',   
            '@(TEST);+@e');
$Replace = array ('',       
              'XXX'
              );

        $data ="this is a TEST  string";
        $data =  preg_replace($Rules,   $Replace,$data);
        echo  $data;

?>
```

Comment: use `str_replace` for such task. it is fast

Comment: thanks, but need to use reg.expr since that is jsut a snapshot of the function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is `(TEST);+` which matches the lister string `TEST` followed by one or more of `+`.

Since there are no `;` in your string `$data`, the match never happens.

Comment: The '@(TEST);+@e' --> @(KOOS)@i